# A question related to cone over X

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

This question is from an assignment which I tried few months earlier but couldn't solve it. I got ill and couldn't ask back then.

> If (X,T) is a topological space , the cone over X is the quotient space $(X\times I)$/ ~, where ~ is the equivalence relation on X$\times$ I defined by (a,1)~ (b,1) for all a,b $\in $X, for all a,b $\in $X and if t$\neq$1 ,(a,t) ~ (b,s) iff a=b and s=t. Prove that if the cone over a topological space (X,T) is locally compact, then the cone over X is compact.

To prove X$\times $ I is compact let there exists an open cover $ \bigcup_iO_i$  covering X$\times$ I /~ .

BuT i am at loss of ideas on how to prove that there exists a finite subcover.

Can you please help with that.

Comment: The statement says the cone over $X$ is locally compact, but you say $X$ is locally compact. This needs an argument. Also, it seems you're assuming countability of the cover, which is not justified. For the record, I believe it is not known whether the quoted statement is true in this complete generality (though it will certainly be true under fairly mild assumptions on $X$).

Comment: @Thorgott Ya you are right  I made a mistake . I mean cone over X is locally compact. and assuming coutable cover was also a mistake. I have edited it

Comment: I doubt that it is true without additional assumptions on $X$.